# EC2 t3.medium instance CPU spikes +90% sometimes

Tags: performance, amazon-ec2, cpanel, cpu-usage

Instance details:

```
Type: t3.medium
vCPUs: 2
RAM: 4
OS: Rocky Linux 9
```

Hourly maximum CPU usage over this week:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTDkC.png)

Cpanel is installed with PHP 8.2 MYSQL 8.0.34

Current memory and CPU usage (`top` output):

```
top - 13:07:30 up 1 day,  8:39,  1 user,  load average: 0.18, 0.17, 0.25
Tasks: 165 total,   1 running, 158 sleeping,   0 stopped,   6 zombie
%Cpu(s): 12.0 us,  2.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 81.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.3 hi,  0.2 si,  3.0 st
MiB Mem :   3602.2 total,    829.4 free,   1365.9 used,   1728.8 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1011.5 free,     12.5 used.   2236.3 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  58342 mysql     20   0 1470328 273704  33368 S   0.7   7.4   4:06.57 mysqld
  60929 dovecot   20   0    8252   4532   3832 S   0.3   0.1   0:03.55 auth
  61170 cpanelc+  20   0    6780   3968   3440 S   0.3   0.1   1:35.05 p0f
      1 root      20   0  104508  14064   9996 S   0.0   0.4   1:21.07 systemd
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.03 kthreadd
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par+
      5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 slub_fl+
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 netns
      8 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker+
     10 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_perc+
     12 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_tas+
     13 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_tas+
     14 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_tas+
     15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.84 ksoftir+
     16 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:13.71 rcu_pre+
     17 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.70 migrati+
```

The website is an online test platform where users can submit a test question by question using AJAX so each user could submit around 20-40 questions per minute for around 45 minutes. The CPU statistics above are mostly from guest visitors not users submitting the questions so it's a bit weird that the instance can't handle around 1000 visitors maybe the CPU spike is because of another process, not users.

We expect more traffic and users soon so we are thinking of one of the following solutions:

1- Upgrade to t3.large or c5a.large.

2- Create an auto-scaling group with 2 more t3.medium in case CPU > 90%.

Is CPU usage related only to vCPU number? if so would it be better to use an instance with 4 vCPU & 16GB RAM?

**Updates about MYSQL**
A- SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables: `718`

D- SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST:

```
Id   User  Host      db      Command  Time  State 
2830 user  localhost dbname  Query    0     init
2831 user  localhost NULL    Sleep    0     NULL
```

E- STATUS: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'STATUS' at line 1

G- SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS:

```
=====================================
2023-10-07 18:41:14 140318059087424 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 8 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 231 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 68899 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 0
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 150
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 150
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 0, OS waits 0
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 0, OS waits 0
RW-sx spins 0, rounds 0, OS waits 0
Spin rounds per wait: 0.00 RW-shared, 0.00 RW-excl, 0.00 RW-sx
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 6877688
Purge done for trx's n:o < 6877688 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 2
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 421793173028056, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421793173027248, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421793173026440, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests ((null))
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
2841 OS file reads, 16006 OS file writes, 9829 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 23, seg size 25, 28 merges
merged operations:
 insert 74, delete mark 1696, delete 449
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 12821, node heap has 3 buffer(s)
Hash table size 12821, node heap has 4 buffer(s)
Hash table size 12821, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
Hash table size 12821, node heap has 7 buffer(s)
Hash table size 12821, node heap has 5 buffer(s)
Hash table size 12821, node heap has 5 buffer(s)
Hash table size 12821, node heap has 3 buffer(s)
Hash table size 12821, node heap has 3 buffer(s)
0.00 hash searches/s, 0.25 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number          3510600244
Log buffer assigned up to    3510600244
Log buffer completed up to   3510600244
Log written up to            3510600244
Log flushed up to            3510600244
Added dirty pages up to      3510600244
Pages flushed up to          3510600244
Last checkpoint at           3510600244
Log minimum file id is       1071
Log maximum file id is       1072
6439 log i/o's done, 0.00 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 0
Dictionary memory allocated 2226952
Buffer pool size   3135
Free buffers       1024
Database pages     2079
Old database pages 747
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 872, not young 22312
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 2517, created 236, written 7472
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 2079, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=58342, Main thread ID=140317588190784 , state=sleeping
Number of rows inserted 167, updated 242, deleted 987, read 337992
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 125, updated 4066, deleted 119, read 146393
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.12 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide CPU usage smoothing suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I updated the question with most of the data required. I will add links for numbers B and C ain comments s I can't add more than 1 link in question.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Here are numbers B and C https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20231007whYwcJVR

Comment: Alarm bells are ringing with the transfernow.net solution you chose.  So, please post TEXT results of B) and C) to justpaste.it and I will be able to pick up your additional data for analysis.

Comment: Global Status: https://justpaste.it/c2bw8

Comment: Global variables: https://justpaste.it/3c5ty

Comment: john  Thank you, Analysis in process.  Wilson Hauck

Comment: Suggestions to consider or your AWS Parameters Group, 
A) connect_timeout=30 
B) innodb_parallel_read_threads=1 
C) innodb_purge_threads=1 
D) read_rnd_buffer_size=16384 
E) net_buffer_length=65536 
F) temptable_max_mmap=67108864 
G) temptable_max_ram+67108864 

There are more opportunities to conserve RAM which is limited. 
View profile, please.

Comment: John, Another significant area is Select_scan has recorded 566 rate per hour.  This is caused by queries that do not have appropriate indexes to speed query completion.  EXPLAIN SELECT sql_no_cache (remainder of your query) will document your absence of index that is needed.  Getting functioning indexes will also reduce CPU Busy significantly.  And your SLOW_QUERY_Log needs to be ON and reviewed until you have eliminated most of the delayed completions.